# How to calculate power requirement of Zener diode for specific frequency of operation?

Tags: power, diodes, zener, flyback

I'm planing to control injector from MCU and this is schematics I came up with.

[image: schematics]

Power supply voltage is 14V, inductance of L1 is 0.0014H, resistance of injector 16.6Ohm, and switching frequency is 166Hz and lower.

If I'm not mistaken, then peak power will be 12W at the moment when M1 stops conducting after inductor is saturated. Does it really mean that diode should be rated the same? Since surge power of diodes are larger than continuous power rating, it makes me think that diode that is rated under 12W should be able to withstand flyback energy for a split second.

What is the correct way of calculating power requirements of D1 given these conditions?

Comment: Why don't you use transistor made for that specific purpose?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič You mean why I do not use transistor with built in diode?

Comment: No. I meant the transistor specifically made for driving the injector

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The idea was to follow a reference design mentioned in some LM.. data sheet. Can you share a couple of device numbers as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume all the energy in the inductance is dumped into the zener. The energy stored in an inductor is

W = \$\text{LI}^2/2\$

Power is just energy per unit time, so multiply by the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The injector's L/R ratio is quite small i.e significantly less than 100 μs hence, we can assume that the energy stored in the inductor is due to the DC current that would flow.

- That DC current is 12 volts / 16.6 Ω = 723 mA.
- This means that the inductor stored energy is 366 μJ.

If the zener is used to dissipate that energy into heat (at 166 Hz), the power will be about 61 mW. This answer assumes that the zener won't be conducting in static conditions i.e. I'm assuming the zener voltage is greater than the maximum supply voltage (shown as 14 volts).